# How to manage source code for common product customizations for different customers

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-fork

My company created a web application for a customer and deployed it successfully more than a year ago. The source code is stored in one git repo.

Now many other different customers with some different needs would like to get this web application BUT with their own (little or big, depending on the customer) customizations. I'm talking about not only look&feel but also new features developed specifically for them on top of the existing and working web application.

In some ways we have a base working "product" that we would like to customize on customers' needs and we cannot manage such customizations with on/off switches, they would be too much and it would be a mess.

Now the problem is how do we manage the source code in an efficient way?

We are thinking about creating a different repo for every customer in order to keep customizations and configurations well separated, every new customer will have a fork of the basic web application. This leads to some problems. Just to name one: when we have to fix a common problem or add/change a common feature we will have to manually replicate the fix/change on N repos.

Is there any pattern, best practice, approach or tool we can apply in order to get things simple?

Comment: Have you manage the source code among multiple customers now?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two ways to manage similar codes among different customers:

- Option 1: manage each customer’s code in a separate branch in the same repo.
- Option 2: manage each customer’s code in separate repositories.

If customers can have permissions for the repo level instead of having permission for a certain branch, you’d better manage the source codes in separate repos so that the customer's privacy not leak.

And for the problem to update N repos based on the common repo, you can cherry-pick the last commit from the common repo to the N repos separately:

```
# In a local customer repo
git remote add common <URL for the common repo> -f
git cherry-pick common/master -X theris
```

And of course, you can cherry-pick the commit from common repo to N repos at the same time through a script.